# how to style or theme organic groups

Tags: organic-groups

How can i present groups on my group-list page similar to this site - 
http://www.popsugar.com/community/groups . i want there to be a picture, group title, short description of the group and total number of members.

further, how can i go about giving groups an option to have profile picture? I presume i'll have to use views but am not sure how. i am using drupal 7 and zen sub theme.

Answer (score 2):

checkout this awesome [og video tutorial](http://modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups), it will show you most of the steps needed. To add a picture to a group you just add a field type "photo" to your group node.
And to display the list of groups you'll use views. I haven't figured out yet how to show the count of members that belong to each group. I posted that as a [separate question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15189/how-to-show-the-count-of-members-that-belong-to-a-group).

Answer (score 0):

Groups are nodes so add a field for image and groups owners can add image to their groups. You can upload a default image to the field for groups without images.

The listing can be done with views and two-column grid view will give you that listing style. I believe Groups module also comes with a group listing view. Edit it to add your image field and other field that you need. Use css to float the image. You can use firebug to look at how they theme the list on that website.