# Does using Views Aggregation break title field as node link?

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

I have a working View that uses aggregate to count members of Organic Groups that I modeled off of the View described [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/15241/1563).

The title of the Groups is also included in the View; however, even though "Link this field to the original piece of content" is selected the View does not configure the Groups title as a link.

Does anyone know if this is because Aggregate is interfering with the link? Should the Aggregate settings on the title field be something specific? Or does it have something to do with the way the Organic Groups Views relationships are defined?

Comment: Does the title display as plain text instead of a link? No special aggregation settings necessary, just "group results together".

Comment: @mototribe: Correct, plain text instead of link. I do have titles set to "group results together" in the aggregation settings for the title field.

Comment: that's strange. The "Link this field to the original piece of content" option should take care of the linking. Are you using the latest versions of views and OG?

Comment: @mototribe:  Views is 7.x-3.0, Organic groups 7.x-1.3.  Latest of both unless I am mistaken.

Comment: This is fixed in the current dev version of views.

Comment: @DanielWehner sounds like an answer to me.  Submit it as such and I'll flag this as answered.

Comment: Can confirm that this is fixed in dev version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this was fixed in a recent dev release of the Views module.