# How to create a view which lists all OG groups and count of og memebers

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups

I have created a Group called School, When user registers to site he will join to a School Group.

After registering to a school i need to show All Groups and Count of Group members joined in a Group.

So instead of writing a Query, can we create a View to get this list ??

Comment: You can Follow the instruction form http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15189/how-to-show-the-count-of-members-that-belong-to-a-group