# How to show the number og members views members views

Tags: organic-groups, views

How do you show the number of members in a group using views please?

I had a look at this post bu unfortunately the relationship have changed in drupal og 7.2

[How to show the count of members that belong to a group?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15189/how-to-show-the-count-of-members-that-belong-to-a-group)

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

It's look the same, please follow instructions from image:
[image]

Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45olm.jpg

Comment: I don't why but it's still not working 1. I've added "OG membership: OG membership from Node group" 2. added "OG membership: Group User from OG membership" > Relationship "OG membership from node group" 3. (Group user from OG membership) COUNT(DISTINCT User: Uid) (Uid)

Comment: What's shown for you?>

Comment: All different group show as a count of 1. Even when they have different amount of memebers

Comment: is your views generated SQL code closer to my?